# Librarian Puppet - Undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (default: NoMethodError)

Tags: vagrant, puppet, librarian-puppet

While Provisioning `Vagrant` VM with [arpitaggarwal/tomcat](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/arpitaggarwal/tomcat/) module from [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com) using `librarian-puppet` works for me with content in `Puppetfile` as follows:

**Puppetfile**:

```
forge "http://forge.puppetlabs.com"
mod "puppetlabs/apt"
mod 'tomcat', :git => 'https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/tomcat.git'
```

And, when I edited **`PuppetFile`** content as:

```
forge "http://forge.puppetlabs.com"
mod "puppetlabs/apt"
mod "arpitaggarwal/tomcat"
```

I got an error:

```
==> default: /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-1.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/source/forge.rb:29:in `versions'
==> default: : 
==> default: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
==> default:  (
==> default: NoMethodError
==> default: )
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-1.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/source/forge.rb:43:in `manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-1.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/source/forge.rb:312:in `manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:16:in `manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:16:in `map'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:16:in `manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/dependency.rb:117:in `cache_manifests!'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/dependency.rb:113:in `manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `scope_checking_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `recursive_resolve'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `scope_checking_manifest'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `map_find'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `scope_checking_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:50:in `resolve'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver.rb:23:in `resolve'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/action/resolve.rb:26:in `run'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:169:in `resolve!'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-1.0.0/lib/librarian/puppet/cli.rb:69:in `install'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `__send__'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `bin!'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:31:in `returning_status'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `bin!'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:47:in `with_environment'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/cli.rb:26:in `bin!'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-1.0.0/bin/librarian-puppet:7
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/librarian-puppet:19:in `load'
==> default:    from /opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/librarian-puppet:19
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you detail how you install `librarian-puppet`

I have a script to install it (based on [this one](https://github.com/purple52/librarian-puppet-vagrant/blob/master/shell/librarian-puppet.sh)) and it installs fine with the following

manifests/init.pp

```
class { 'tomcat':  }
```

Puppetfile

```
forge "http://forge.puppetlabs.com"

mod "puppetlabs/apt"
mod "arpitaggarwal/tomcat"
```

output of `vagrant up`

```
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with main.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat/Exec[apt-update]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat/Package[tomcat7]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat/File[/etc/default/tomcat7]/content: content changed '{md5}49f3fe5de425aca649e2b69f4495abd2' to '{md5}2694682a4593e8d185d428f6bdeb39e2'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat/File[/etc/tomcat7/server.xml]/content: content changed '{md5}523967040584a921450af2265902568d' to '{md5}676faee02c60f2e593530339cadf4791'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat/Exec[service-restart]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: Finished catalog run in 389.24 seconds
```

Tomcat was installed and on the VM

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ librarian-puppet version
librarian-puppet v1.5.0
vagrant@precise64:~$
```

**Previous Answer**
I think in newer version of librarian, you need to use `forge "https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com"`

Comment: It leads to ```Unable to find module 'puppetlabs/apt' on https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com```

Comment: Fixed with `librarian-puppet v1.5.0`. Not sure if it's a bug in v1.0.0, anyways, thanks :)

Comment: welcome - good thing to do the bounty, I forgot about the question !